# A wrong address's email sent on AT command error via ssmtp

Tags: linux, ssmtp

I followed this instruction to setup an email client, 
http://zackreed.me/articles/39-send-system-email-with-gmail-and-ssmtp

All works fine but when I use at / crontab.

for example,

at now

abcd1234

Since there is no such command, an email saying abcd1234 not found is sent to 
linux-user-name@gmail-username@gmail.com
instead of expected gmail-username@gmail.com

Is there any way to override the return address for error/system message on ssmtp instead of setting MAILTO on crontab?

Answer (score 0):

try adding "username: your@email.address" to /etc/aliases, where `username` is the username that your at job or cron job is running as.

Comment: Thanks, but /etc/aliases doesn't help

Comment: I got this failure delivery email in my gmail account. 

Email title = Output from your job 44, 

Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     linuxusername@gmailusername@gmail.com

sh: 27: dwdwdwdwd: not found